# can not write csv file in UTF--8 format by using spark, it saved in binary format

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

In our hadoop new built cluster,  when we try to create CSV file using spark, csv file saved in binary format even though we enforce it to save in utf-8,
but same spark code works perfectly on old QA hadoop cluster.

here is the sample,

```
df.coalesce(1)
   .write
   .format("csv")
   .mode(saveMode)
   .option("header",true)
   .option("encoding", "UTF-8") 
   .save(hdfspath)
```

Any idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: Everything is 'binary', including CSV and UTF-8. I think you have to share some more details on what you are actually seeing vs. what are you expecting.

Comment: @Evert- in our old hadoop cluster, csv file stored in hdfs temp location and we can cat (read) the csv file. We can see the actual digit/number. But in our new built hadoop cluster, when we pass cat command for csv file, we can not read the file. The file is not human readable. Even though we pass UTF-8 in our code. Any idea?

Comment: By default Spark saves files in parquet format. You need to show your code

Comment: same code works in Old cluster but not in new build cluster. The code is--> it is importing hive tables and save CSV file in hdfs location. In old cluster, we do not need to do anything but in new cluster even though we pass UTF-8, it does not work. .csv file created but we can not read as it looks binary format................... here is the sampe,---> df.coalesce(1)
  .write
  .format("csv")
  .mode(saveMode)
  .option("header",true)
  .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
  .save(hdfspath)

Comment: Well, new cluster must use a different version of Spark or Hadoop... What versions are they? Also, don't use `write.format("csv").save()` use `write.csv()` - https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/sql-data-sources-csv.html

Comment: If you are using EMR can you check if encryption is enabled on the cluster ?